# Execute dependency when calling a class in Laravel (IoC Container)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container

I'm creating a little Google Analytics service by myself to play around and learn how to do this kind of stuff.

So I have a `AnalyticsServiceProvider` which contains:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('analytics', function () {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('Hodor Application');
        $client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($account, $scope, $key));

        return new AnalyticsService(new Google_Service_Analytics($client));
    });
}
```

My `AnalyticsService` has a `doSomething()` method which will get data from the API.
I've bound the `analytics` IoC binding to a `Analytics` facade.

So while that's setup, I can call `Analytics::doSomething();` from my controller. Which works fine.

But I want to inject the `AnalyticsService` into my controller from the constructor.. Like so:

```
public function __construct(AnalyticsService $service)
{
    $this->service = $service;
}
```

But, this isn't working because the code from the `AnalyticsServiceProvider` wont be executed.
Is there any way where I can execute this, upon injecting the `AnalyticsService` in my constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the IoC container key be the actual class name:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('AnalyticsService', function () {
        // register as before...
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know it was flexable like that. I must have read over it in the docs!